# Dynamic radio buttons in Toloka

Tags: toloka

One of the projects we want to evaluate with Toloka requires having dynamic choices/options based on the Business entity.  Typically, these values are static. Does Toloka support having dynamic values for options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concatenation (https://yandex.com/support/toloka-requester/concepts/t-components/helpers.html#helpers__concat) for dynamic radio buttons or checkboxes.